# how to solve:npm run build/dev: missing script?

Tags: npm

I'm trying to run node, but for some reason the local npm install of node isn't working.

The package is there:

```
$ npm run dev npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "jshint" 
npm ERR! node v5.6.0 
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! missing script: dev 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: 
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR!     /Users/me/workspace/testapp/npm-debug.log
```

I can work with `npm install`, but `run npm dev` is not correct.

Answer (score 29):

You saw that error because there was probably not a script named dev in the "scripts" section of your package.json

`npm install` and `npm run dev` are two completely different ideas

1. `npm install` will run through *dependencies* section of the package.json and fetch/install the modules in that list
2. `npm run dev` will check the *scripts* section of the package.json and try to find a script titled "dev" and if there is no script named "dev" it will error out as you experienced (Dev is absolutely not a special word by the way, if you ever need to use the scripts section in a future project you can name the scripts anything you want.)

As an example, make a new folder and copy the following into a file named package.json inside of it

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "echo This is the DEV script",
    "abc": "echo This is the abc script",
    "xyz": "echo This is the xyz script",
    "start":"echo This is the special start script"
  }
}
```

From your terminal, cd into the directory you made containing that sample package.json and try the following commands and see what happens:

`npm run dev` you should see on your screen "This is the dev script"

`npm run abc` you see on your scree "This is the abc script"

`npm run xyz` you should see on your screen "This is the xyz script"

`npm run linkxu1989` you should see on your screen a similar error to what you saw above since there's no script named "linkxu1989" in the scripts part of the package.json

`npm start` you should see on your screen "This is the special start script" (Note that start IS a special name. You can run with just `npm start` or with `npm run start` like all the others`

Bottom line: Check the "scripts" section of package.json and to run any of them just enter `npm run SCRIPT_NAME`

Hope that helps and good luck w/ NPM!

See here for more details

- https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json
- http://browsenpm.org/package.json (don't worry about understanding everything in it, all you should think about at this point is what's in "dependencies"
- http://jsonlint.com/ (If you ever manually edit a package.json, run it through this checker to help catch any formatting mistakes. The package.json is a "json" file so it needs to be in a PERFECT format which means no trailing commas, double quotes only, etc etc)
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

It means in your “package.json” (in the folder in which you run “npm run build”), there’s NO “build” script. A quick check: run “npm run lalala” in your terminal/command prompt. It will show “missing script: lalala”.

So if it’s your package, add the “build” script. Just go to the package.json in your code editor and add the key value entry as JSON.

If it’s a module/package you downloaded from npmjs.org, then refer to the documentation to see what command they support.

Note: “npm build” is a completely different command from “npm run build”. All “scripts” commands except start and test need to be run with “run”.