# Npm Install Permission Error

Tags: node.js, wordpress, npm-install

So I'm attempting to run npm install into my WP theme folder so I can convert .scss to css.

When I try to install this is all I see:

```
Web-Stations-Mac-Pro:ideabased matmorse$ npm install
npm WARN matmorse@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN matmorse@1.0.0 No repository field.

removed 7 packages in 1.661s
```

I've tried uninstalling NPM and NODE and re installing it with Brew.  I've also tried correcting my permissions.  The node_modules folder never installs.

NPM -v : 5.3.0

No - v: 8.3.0

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's definitely about your rights. copy package.json to your home folder and try it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have package.json in the folder so you can't use the `npm install` command, since npm install looks for the package.json (that's why you are getting no description found error) .

You can use `npm install node-sass` to install the `node-sass` module.

You can refer the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for further clarification on `npm install`.

Comment: Okay I see that on my other projects there is a package.json.  How is this file created?  I've never had to add it, it just has always been there.

Comment: `npm init` will work. Then edit the package.json for downloading the modules or you can simply use `npm install module_name`

Comment: Okay I added the package.json but `npm install` didn't install the node-modules folder like normal so I ran the `npm install node-sass` which did install the correct folder, but `npm run build` is missing the build script.

Comment: refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071819/how-to-solvenpm-run-build-dev-missing-script)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following commands:

1. `npm config get prefix`
2. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`