# Npm missing script: dev

Tags: npm, webpack

I am working on project that uses webapck , nodejs

I got npm error says

> missing script: dev

I have already tried including dev attribute in package.json file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve:npm run build/dev: missing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071819/how-to-solvenpm-run-build-dev-missing-script)

Comment: you should show at least the package.json file, it's hard to help with a problem without any information (aside the error) and possibility to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your `package.json` this is only a guess, but you need to add a `"dev"` attribute to your `package.json` below the `"test"` attribute in the `"scripts"` object. Since this is tagged in webpack and assuming you're running webpack v4, I'm guessing you're trying to run `webpack-dev-server`. Here is what I use as a `"dev"` script (feel free to change this to whatever you want):

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors --mode development --open",
```

And then run either one of these commands in your terminal (depending on which package manager you're using:

```
npm run dev 
yarn dev
```